Flutter WebView inside NestedScrollView is scrolling independently
This is how the code is currently:
final WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
  ..loadRequest(someUri);

    return MyScaffold(
      title: title,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, _) {
          return [
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                    context),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: _webViewNavigation(controller, context),
                ))
          ];
        },
        body: WebView(controller: controller),
      ),
    );

}
If this WebView is replaced by a SliverListView() - this works absolutely fine. However, with a WebView, the scrolling for WebView works independently from that of the ScrollView. Any solutions to this?
The WebView has:
          gestureRecognizers: {}
        ..add(Factory(() => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),

